# "Nitrogen (gas) is physisorbed over iron (metal) at room temperature": Is this for real?

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, erratum, adsorption

My copy (PDF) of Levine's *Physical Chemistry (6th ed.)*, page 570-571, section: "*Adsorption of Gases on Solids*", states:

> Physical adsorption is nonspecific. For example, $\ce{N2}$ will be *physically adsorbed* on any solid provided the *temperature is low* enough.

and

> ... N2 is *chemisorbed* at *room temperature* on $\ce{Fe, W, Ca,}$ and $\ce{Ti}$ but not on $\ce{Ni, Ag, Cu,}$ or $\ce{Pb}$.

Alright, fair enough, thanks for the examples.

*But*

A bunch of (notoriously error-prone-citation-deficient) course books issued by my school, all unambiguously concur on the contrary:

> At $\ce{83K}$, $\ce{N2}$ is *physically adsorbed* over iron metal. Raising the temperature to $\ce{773K}$ then results in the nitrogen being *chemisorbed* over the metal as atomic nitrogen.

Which in other words is: "At room temperature, nitrogen is physically adsorbed. The nitrogen is chemisorbed after the temperature's raised to 500 degrees Celsius".

But this contradicts the information in Levine's book.

---

**Who's right here: Levine or my book?** (References are welcome) O:)

---

EDIT-

LinearChristmas has correctly pointed out that the temperatures at which the physical adsorption --> chemisorption transition takes place depends on pressure as well as the nature of the iron surface.

In light of this, I'll modify my question:

Q- My coursebook and Levine's lists (implicitly in Levine's case) the transition from physical adsorption --> chemisorption at different temperatures. Between the two, which one lists the more *improbable* temperatures?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this can be answered as is. This probably isn't entirely your fault; general textbooks tend to be secretive when it comes to experimental details. Firstly, what are the pressures and how were measurements done on each? It is also incorrect to assume an iron as being equivalent to some other iron. Surface properties, including porosity, are strongly dependent on how the material has been handled. I  further recommend adding references for both sources. Finally, is it also possible $773\ \mathrm{K}$ was simply a typo for $273\ \mathrm{K}$? (just in case)

Comment: @Linear A good point! Not sure about the iron surface/crystal, but I just assumed this is carried out at atmospheric pressure (unlikely, but I wouldn't know any better). As for the 773/273 typo, it *could* be a typo, but  three different booklets (all issued by our teacher) carry 773 in it. :'(

Comment: Okay. Sadly, we still have to know more about the iron to make an informed comparison. For example, [10.1039/TF9595502166](https://doi.org/10.1039/TF9595502166) reports on some iron catalysts having chemisorbed N2 at measurable rates from $473\ \mathrm{K}$. Their own sample, ‘highly reduced singly promoted iron catalyst’, reported similar results for a temperature of $273\ \mathrm{K}$. There is another caveat. The second source in OP: *chemisorbed over the metal as atomic nitrogen*. Note that there are other ways of nitrogen chemisorbing, though mononitrogen could be most common (I'm unsure).

Comment: @Linear < *Nods sadly* > This seems more painful than I first thought. I suppose then, any potential answer would be aiming to dismiss either one of the two claims (in my post) as "improbable" rather than outright "incorrect". Thanks for the insight! O:)

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. I do see a scenario where this is closed as primarily opinion-based. To be sure, we may wait for other responses since this is a relatively new thread.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misinterpreting the course book issued by your school since it never mentions what happens at room temperature.

For me, none of the books is (seems) wrong, because they do not contradict each other. I will mention each affirmation including the textbook which said it (Levine, or Your book):

- Levine says: N<sub>2</sub> is physically adsorbed on any solid at low temperature. This agrees with your text saying N<sub>2</sub> is physically adsorbed at $\pu{83 K}$ on Fe.
- Levine says: N<sub>2</sub> is chemisorbed at room temperature on Fe. Your book does not mention about room temperature. No contradiction here.
- Your book says N<sub>2</sub> is chemisorbed at $\pu{773 K}$. Levine does not mention this temperature, but if it already occurred at room temperature it will also occur at higher.

The only 'gray area' is at which temperature does N<sub>2</sub> get chemisorbed (room temperature or not?). [In the article of de Boer *et al.*](http://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/articlelanding/1959/tf/tf9595502166#!divAbstract) mentioned by @Linear Christmas above, they measure chemisorption of N<sub>2</sub> even at $\pu{23.9 ^\circ C}$.

They clearly state:

> Hitherto it has been reported in literature$^{1,2}$ that an iron catalyst starts to chemisorb nitrogen at a measurable rate at about $\pu{200 ^\circ C}$. The chemisorption activity of our intensely reduced sample was considerably higher; already at $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$, nitrogen was chemisorbed at a measurable rate.

**Reference:**

J. J. F. Scholten, P. Zwietering, J. A. Konvalinka, J. H. de Boer, "Chemisorption of nitrogen on iron catalysts in connection with ammonia synthesis. Part 1.—The kinetics of the adsorption and desorption of nitrogen," *Trans. Faraday Soc.* **1959**, *55*, 2166-2179 (https://doi.org/10.1039/TF9595502166).

Comment: "*Raising the temperature to 773K then results in the nitrogen being chemisorbed...*" <--- That sounds like my book says that at 773K and above nitrogen is chemisorbed, meaning at lower temperatures (including room temp) it is *physically adsorbed*... so I'm not very confident about your 2nd and 3rd bullet point. First bullet is okay.

Comment: Being chemisorbed above 773 K does not exclude being also chemisorbed below.